# Python script to executable error with pandas (py2exe)

Tags: python, pandas, py2exe

I am creating an executable from a python script using py2exe. I made an executable of the same script in the past and it worked, but I wanted to change something and included the pandas module in the script. Now I am not able to make the executable run. I am able to run the setup.py script and create the dist folder with py2exe, but whenever I try to run the .exe file I get an error and in the log file it says:

```
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 64, in init pandas._libs.lib(pandas\_libs\lib.c:91325)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in_find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<loader>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<loader>", line 6, in __load
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable.pxd", line 7, in init pandas._libs.interval (pandas\_libs\interval.c:111385)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HashTable'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or does anyone know what module is good to use to make an executable of a scipt that imports pandas?

My setup.py script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe


setup(windows=['KontrollerElvegVegnett.py'], requires=['pandas'])
```

Comment: Redarding the question about another module to make executables: have you tried Cx_Freeze ? [link](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I tried Cx_Freeze now, does not work for me either. The error is now: Import Error: Missing required dependencies ['numpy'].

Comment: You should find "_methods" in `site-packages/numpy/core/` and copy it to `build/exe.win32-2.7/numpy/core/` (according to this [link](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/205) issue page on github)

Comment: This works! Thank you!

Comment: Nice, good for you! :)